# Parralel websocket connections. Imitating UDP

Tags: node.js, tcp, websocket, udp, webrtc

I'm building a fast paced webgl game and as a common problem I'm experiencing is the retransmits of lost TCP(websockets) packets on higher packet send / receive frequency.
Two options I considered:
 1. using webrtc with node.js client to simulate node.js as a peer and connect it to browser for UDP use. So far unsuccessful to connect it to heroku, though works great locally. Is this possible, are there any limitations I overlooked which made it impossible for me to implement into heroku?
 2. using multiple websocket connections from single client to a single user on server. Server & client would discard those messages that come from an older tcp packet (let's say 30-60ms delay due to retrasmits). Therefore making it seems like it's a UDP connection. Is this valid, would those connections break each other or work independantly, are there other really bad drawbacks to this method ? This would be an easier alternative to implement.
The reason I would not like to connect two clients via webrtc, but rather need it to connect to server is security. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just did some testing on multiple websocket connections, it seems they are waiting on each other to complete.

Comment: webrtc within node.js application works just fine, though fails running on heroku app with a crash: segmentation failure.